# Is it possible write this query without cursor

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql database
The schema of department is

```
Department Table

Deptid     DeptName
1          CEO
2          HR
3          IT
4          Dev
5          QA

Employee table
Empid    EmpName    managerid   deptid
1        E1                     1
2        E2         1           2
3        E3         1           3
4        E4         3           4
5        E5         4           4
6        E6         4           4
7        E7         3           5
8        E8         7           5
9        E9         7           5
```

I need output as

```
deptid  parentdept  count
1                   1
2       1           1
3       1           1
4       3           3
5       3           3
```

Parent department is department which belongs to manager of employee.
It means It department CEO is parent department of IT and HR because IT and HR managers report to CEO dept manager.
It means It department IT is parent department of Dev and QA because DEV and QA managers report to IT dept manager.

```
  deptid  parentdept   count
    CEO                   1
    HR       CEO          1
    IT       CEO          1
    DEV      IT           3
    QA       IT           3

Tree representation of it is
                       CEO-(deptid 1)E1
HR-(deptid 2)E2                               IT-(deptid 3)E3
                         DEV-(deptid 4)E4                              QA(deptid 5)E7
                  E5-(deptid 4)   E6-(deptid 4)           E8-(deptid 5)   E9-(deptid 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the managerid shoudn't be equal to the any empid in the same department rows by your descriptions.

```
select A.deptid,B.parentdept,A.count from (select deptid,
count(*) as count from Employee group by deptid) as A 
left join 
(select t1.deptid, t3.deptid as parentdept from Employee t1,Employee t3 where t1.managerid not
   in (select Empid from Employee t2 where t2.deptid=t1.deptid) 
   and t1.managerid=t3.empid) as B 
on A.deptid=B.deptid;
```

if I missed something in the logic, apologies in advance.